# Are labels followed by colon or equal sign in gas?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

having this:

```
.text
    .globl main
str:
    .string "hello world"
len = .-str #a strange assignment
main:
    mov $1, %eax
    mov $1, %edi
    movabs $str, %rsi
    mov $len, %rdx
    syscall 
    call exit
```

1) here is `str` with colons (as I see usually), but then `len` is assigned by `=`. I do not think that is because the `str` is address, and `len` is number (and thus different type), but why one can be assigned different ways? Or are both labels?

2) Why to use `mov str(%rip), %rsi`, when I can use `movabs $str, %rsi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are followed by `:`

An `=` isn't a label, it defines a symbol as an assemble-time constant the way `.set` or `.equ` does.  This is getting the assembler to calculate the length of the string for you, at assemble time.

`.` is the current position.  Think of `.` as an implicit label at the start of this line.  You could equivalently have put a `str_end:` label after the string and done `len = str_end - str`.

---

> Why to use `mov str(%rip), %rsi`, when I can use `movabs $str, %rsi`?

Those aren't equivalent!  `mov str(%rip), %rsi` would load 8 bytes from that address, getting the string data into a register.  But you need a *pointer* to the string in a register as an arg for a `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` system call.  Try it in a debugger and/or `strace` and watch it fail.

That's why the `movabs` in this code uses `$str`, to get the address as a 64-bit immediate.

However, that's [the worst way to put a label/symbol address into a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register-in-gnu-assembler).  `movabs` with an 8 byte immediate amounts to a 10-byte instruction total, and being absolute it needs runtime fixups in a PIE executable or library (ELF shared object) when the loader chooses an actually base address for the executable.

You actually want `LEA str(%rip), %rsi` (7 bytes), or in a [non-PIE Linux executable where static addresses fit in the low 31 bits of address space, `mov $str, %esi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).

Comment: sory, no *double* colon. I have mistyped. But anyway, if `=` is the same (or similar) to `.set`, then Why i can *not* do `len: .set .-str`?

Comment: @autistic456: Because that's not the syntax for `.set`.  (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Set.html).  It would be `.set len,  . - str`.  .set is a directive.

Comment: Ok, and then how differ `lea str(%rip), %rsi` from `movabs $str, %rsi`. Both are loading addres

Comment: @autistic456: read the [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) Q&A I linked.  7-byte RIP-relative LEA is shorter and more efficient, and position-independent.

Comment: Just read it. It seems you explain, the `movasb` is used for jumps, and therefor for first function instruction, but bad for immediate. But still both are *just* address. Once is for data (immediate) and the other for tex (first function instruction), so why does linux supports it? I cannot jump wit `lea toJump(%rip)`?

Comment: @autistic456: uh, no, either work for any label address.  (Except in a "large" code model, in which case you might need movabs.)  The difference is absolute vs. PC-relative, and in code-size.

Comment: so in "large code model", where I want to get to address very high (and therefor use all 8 bytes, the `movabs` manipulate with - or is ti 10 bytes?), then I will use absolute address and not relative. But I can still use relative, it is just a number, so again, Why not use relative address from rip offset (as is `lea toJump(%rip)`) even for "large" code models?

Comment: @autistic456: because the RIP-relative addressing mode only uses a 32-bit relative displacement, enough to cover 2GiB of code + static data (able to reach any address from any other address). [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400)  That's why the large code model can't use it.